# How can I put List value in thenReturn for unit testing?

Tags: java, unit-testing

I use mockito to test a data get from a website. It will return a list. I put a list below but it does not work.

```
  @Test
  void getData() throws IOException {
    when(dataService.getData()).thenReturn("123123" ,"fghf","fghgfh");
```

Intellj popped up it requires `List<String>t, list<String>...ts`

Any suggestion?

Comment: `thenReturn(Arrays.asList(...)) `

Answer (score 2):

You should create a List of strings and use it as argument for .thenReturn();

```
@Test
void getData() throws IOException {
    final List<String> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
    dataList.add("123123");
    dataList.add("fghf");
    dataList.add("fghgfh");
    when(dataService.getData()).thenReturn(dataList);
}
```

Comment: `Arrays.asList`, `ImmutableList.of` or java9 `List.of` are nice shorthands as well.

Answer (score 1):

I got a answer. Thanks slvtn

```
  @Test
  void getUnixTimeWithNumber() throws IOException {
    when(dataService.getData()).thenReturn(List.of("1231","unixtime: 1213"));
 }
}
```